# Why java.library.path is not working on ubuntu?

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I am working on an java component which need some libraries i.e `.dll` for windows system and `.so` files for Linux system. So I prepared an java application in netbeans and added some dependency jars and build the project.

**Execution on Windows:**

When I tried to run jar file on Windows system using command `java -jar appName.jar` I got `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` so I specified java.library.path while execution like `java -Djava.library.path=full\\path\\to\\libs -jar appName.jar` and it got run successfully on Windows.

**Execution on Linux(ubuntu) :**

When I tried to execute same jar file on ubuntu with the same command `java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/libs -jar appName.jar` I got error saying some .so file are not found on specified location (I checked file location and permissions, all is ok)

***Updated (added error):***

> ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-dx2480-MT-KL969AV:~/Desktop$ java
>   -Djava.library.path=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin -jar JavaApplication4.jar
>
> initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path bin
>   bin/jcef_helper: error while loading shared libraries: libcef.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

contains of bin folder

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1483321 Jun 18  2014 cef.pak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   3258231 Jun 18  2014 devtools_resources.pak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    971264 Jun 11  2014 ffmpegsumo.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   9994752 Jun 11  2014 icudt.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    429568 Jun 18  2014 jcef.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    481488 Jun 18  2014 jcef_helper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    233984 Jun 18  2014 jcef_helper.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  53280768 Jun 11  2014 libcef.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 105317136 Jun 18  2014 libcef.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1309288 Jun 18  2014 libffmpegsumo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1047296 Jun 18  2014 libjcef.so drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Dec 23 11:29 locales
```

By some searching I come to know that I have try with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable so I created an sh file having command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libs

java -jar /path/to/appName.jar
```

and when I run sh file my program runs successfully.

**So my question is why java.library.path is not works for ubuntu (linux)? Is it like `java.library.path` is only for windows?**

Comment: `-Djava.library.path=path/to/libs` is this a typo or do you use relative path here ?

Comment: Sorry it's typo, I use full path like C:\winlibs\ for windows and \home\ubuntu\Desktop\Linuxlibs

Comment: You should provide the error messeage here for a better anwser.

Comment: @secmask, added error in question. Please find Updated (added error):

Comment: You specify `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin`, could be that libs here need other libs that is not here ? Remember `java.library.path` can hold multiple paths.

Comment: @PeterMmm, but specifying the same path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is working, How?

Comment: Your comment above is confusing: did you use \home\ubuntu\Desktop\Linuxlibs or /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Linuxlibs? Linux uses forward slashes as file separator.

Comment: @bernardn, So so sorry again typo, I have used proper slash :) , Sorry again.

Comment: Could that be a mismatch of 32/64bit Java ? There is also a `LD_LIBRARYN32_PATH` environment var.

Comment: @PeterMmm, I don't think so. Because as per JCEF the provide binary distribution only for 64 bit JVM and I also using 64 bit OS with 64 bit JVM.

Comment: please provide `ls -l /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin`

Comment: hello you can use `jarsplice` for creating a native jar application here's the [useful link of jarsplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)

Comment: Try this command `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin java -Djava.library.path=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin -jar /jar/path.jar`

Comment: @secmask, but after using LD_LIBRARY_PATH there is no need of Djava.library.path

Comment: oh, just to make sure, it base on example of `run.sh` from jcef binary package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is why java.library.path is not works for ubuntu (linux)? Is it like java.library.path is only for windows?

It does work, we use it a lot. Start your application with `-XshowSettings:properties` and take a look at the search path for debugging.

We usually deploy the libraries as a package to `/usr/local/lib`, since the libraries are often used by other components too. Don't forget to call `ldconfig` after placing a new library in there (so much for the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` part).

As far as i remember it *should* be enough with just adding the folder with `-Djava.library.path` if i recall correctly. I will look into it and tell you later to clarify.

Also please post `readlink -f /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin`, `file /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/libcef.so` and `ldd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/libcef.so`.

**Update:**
I will try to explain why things work and why not.

Lets talk about `java.library.path`. This property is used by the VM for looking up libraries. Take a look at [java.lang.System#load*(String libName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for reference. The `java.library.path` property has some paths pre-set, the following shows the output on my ubuntu box:

```
ortang@vbox-devel:~$ java -XshowSettings:properties
Property settings:
    ...
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        /usr/lib/jni
        /lib
        /usr/lib
```

Be aware that using this property **will overwrite** the existing property.

```
ortwin@vbox-devel:~$ java -Djava.library.path=/some/other/folder:/yet/another/one -XshowSettings:properties
Property settings:
    ...
    java.library.path = /some/other/folder
        /yet/another/one
```

So far so good. The JVM is looking only in the folders defined in that property!

The libraries you make the JVM to load will most likely have dependencies to other libraries. Be aware that these dependencies are looked up by the operating system, just as any other shared library!

So to solve your problem you have to make sure that the libraries you load have their dependencies resolved! Use `ldd` for debugging that matter.

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable does a similar job, as it adds paths that will be used for library lookup by the OS. I am no fan of using it in production environments.

Comment: yes, by coping all files from `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin` to `/usr/local/lib` worked for command `java -Djava.library.path=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin -jar appName.jar`. That too without using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: `readlink -f /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin` gives `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin`

Comment: `file /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/libcef.so`  gives `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/libcef.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x2cba7c71da1e6000d154c84e3de947aa9380a2fd, not stripped
`

Comment: I tried `file` with jcef_helper because according to error as i posted in question libcef.so file is not found while loding of jcef_helper `file /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/jcef_helper` so  gives `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/jcef_helper: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x3cc71c45cf3d5d9e27f89cab9c5ea6b04165343a, not stripped`

Comment: for `jcef_helper` it says `(uses shared libs)` so i tried `ldd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin/jcef_helper`in output it says `libcef.so => not found` but after adding files to `/usr/local/lib` file path is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess for your problem is that you have to use both java.library.path **and** LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Indeed, j.l.p is for java to load you JNI library while L_L_P is for the operating system to load the shared library and any dependent libraries. If your shared library depends on other libraries in other paths you have to list those paths.

Comment: Ohh so is that like setting j.l.p for Windows taking care to load libraries with there depended library whereas in linux setting just j.l.p is loading dependent library in my case its `jcef_helper` but jcef_helper need libcef.so file which is not loading so that we need to setup L_L_P which sets environment variable and os will takes care to load library and there dependent library, correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Windows relies on different parameters for loading DLLs, one of which is the same path as the loading library. Another one is the paths listed in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Okay, I just http://kalblogs.blogspot.in/2009/01/java.html this article, now understand why j.l.p is not enough for linux sys. Its like `jcef_helper` needs `libcef.so` but as we are setting j.l.p which resolves library (jcef_helper) but this library references or is dynamically linked another file (libcef.so) which is not loaded by setting j.l.p THOUGH BOTH FILES ARE IN SAME DIR I.E /home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin, where as L_L_P loads all the libraries with its referenced or dynamically linked files.

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. So, please specify both L_L_P and j.l.p and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

it's seem that jcef did not find it's depenencies, try `ldd libcef.so |grep "not found"` and `ldd libjcef.so |grep "not found"` and fix the missing libraries. On my machine (ubuntu 14.04) It miss libudev.so.0 , my machine has `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` so trick it by `ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0` and `sudo ldconfig` to reload ld cache.

Comment: for `libudev` i already fix. try for `ldd jcef_helper` it will say `libcef.so` not found. at least in my case

Comment: by coping all files from `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin` to `/usr/local/lib` worked for command `java -Djava.library.path=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin -jar appName.jar`. That too without using export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Please read answer given by @OrtwinAngermeier and my findings in comments of the same answer.

Comment: java load `libjcef.so` from it's code, from the error message, It can be said that java can see and load `libjcef.so` but when `libjcef.so` load `libcef.so` as its dependency, error is occur. Said that it could not find `libcef.so` in search path. You could try another way is create file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cef.conf` with content `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bin` then reload ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`, also test that LD_LIBRARY_PATH work on your machine as normal.

Comment: Okay, will try. but one question is still in my mind, can i ask?

Comment: when in windows all the libraries and referenced or shared libraries are automatically get loaded when its kept in same dir, but in linux it's not done though both `jcef_helper` and `libcef.so` are kept in same dir as you see in `ls -l`. Normally we say that keeping libraries and its referenced library into same folder doesn't make any problem. then why I am facing problem in ubuntu?

Comment: it the way they make linux work, linux does not look for share library in the same path as executable file by default. But you can  include executable path in search path by use `rpath`, see `readelf -d libjcef.so |grep runpath`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, I use "-Djava.library.path", but it does't work.
I add "-Dsun.boot.library.path" as a try, it works!

try:

```
java -Dsun.boot.library.path=/path/to/libs -jar appName.jar
```

Comment: This is something of a hack if it works and possibly not related to the question -- `sun.boot.library.path` serves a different purpose to `java.library.path`, in that the former is for libraries related to the JVM itself and the latter is for libraries related to the project you're giving to it to run.